# Filling unnamed text fields in Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

I'm trying to fill some unnamed fields using `$mech->fields` but I ran out of hair on my head to pull off, please help.

```
<input id="af-city" class="input-field af-city" autocomplete="address-level2" type="text" aria-required="true" placeholder="">
<input id="af-zip" class="input-field postal-code-validate af-zip" autocomplete="postal-code" type="text" aria-required="true" placeholder="">
```

have tried using xpath, no use, adding a dot or a hash in front of the id to let `$mech` know this is an id not a name, no use.

```
$mech->field( ".af-city", "Monsey");
$mech->field( {xpath => '//*[@id="af-zip"]'}, "10952");
```

Comment: What is going to happen with that form? If you submit that, it will not be included in the request without a name. There has to be some Javascript that does tings to the values. The classes `input-field` and `postal-code-validate` and the `autocomplete` and the fact that there are ids but not names support that. Mechanize::Firefox cannot execute Javascript, though. I doubt even if you manage to put something in them it will be of much use. Inspect the communication on the page with a real browser and look at what it does, then try to simulate that instead.